# Trouble with margins & plot sizes in multiple figure plot in pdf

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a lot of plots and dump them to a pdf.  Some of the plots naturally go together, so I'd like them to be on the same page of the pdf.  However, either the dimensions get distorted, or the titles and x-axis labels don't show up.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100)

pdf(file="My pdf.pdf", paper="letter")
  par(mfrow=c(2,1))                     # squished
  hist(x, freq=FALSE)
  lines(density(x))
  qqnorm(x)
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
pdf(file="My pdf.pdf", paper="letter")
  par(mfrow=c(2,1), pin=c(3,3))         # no titles, etc.
  hist(x, freq=FALSE)
  lines(density(x))
  qqnorm(x)
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
pdf(file="My pdf.pdf", paper="letter")
  par(mfrow=c(2,1), pin=c(3,3), mar=c(4,2,2,1))  # squished again
  hist(x, freq=FALSE)
  lines(density(x))
  qqnorm(x)
dev.off()

pdf(file="My pdf.pdf", paper="letter")
  par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(4,2,2,1), pin=c(3,3))  # now titles but overlapping
  hist(x, freq=FALSE)
  lines(density(x))
  qqnorm(x)
dev.off()
```

[image]

What I'd like is not just code to do this, but to understand how this works.  For example, why does changing the order of the arguments in the last two versions make so much difference.  Note that, I will have differing numbers of plots to go together (sometimes 2, 4 or 8) on a page, even though I only demonstrate the simplest case here.  Some code that will scale plots nicely automatically might be nice, if it exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My general recommendations would be to (1) stick to only one unit of measurement, inches or lines, and (2) do some arithmetic to determine how big your device size needs to be to fit what you're plotting.

You're mixing `mar` and `pin` which use lines and inches. I certainly don't know how tall 1 inch plus 1 line is going to be off the top of my head (although I'm sure we could hack something together to calculate it).

So imagine you're telling R to plot two plots on top of each other, and each is 3 inches high (`pin = c(3,3)`). I think the part you're forgotten is that the default device size for `pdf` is only 7 inches tall.

So if we set the figure margins using inches, and then adjust the device size to be the appropriate height:

```
pdf(file="My pdf.pdf", paper="letter",width = 7,height = 10)
  par(mfrow=c(2,1), mai=c(1,0.5,0.5,0.25), pin=c(3,3))
  hist(x, freq=FALSE)
  lines(density(x))
  qqnorm(x)
dev.off()
```

that should work. (I always add a little extra room.)

Comment: The part about `pin` & `mar` is just b/c that's what I had been playing w/ before posting; I've tried `mai` & gotten the same thing. That the size of the pdf is 7 in is really useful information. It's the `width=7` & `height=10` that I think I was missing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @gung Setting `mai` and `pin` (or `mar` and `pin`) are definitely interacting in a way I don't quite understand. You can see it directly by setting each individually and checking the value of `pin` as you go.

Comment: How would I check the value of `pin` mid-execution? I don't understand how I get different results by re-ordering the arguments to par, but adding `width` & `height` does do the trick.

Comment: @gung In a clean session, run `par(mfrow = c(2,1))` and then `par("pin")`. Then run `par(pin = c(3,3))` and then `par("pin")`. Finally, run `par(mar = c(4,2,2,1))` and then run `par("pin")` again.

Comment: I don't follow that. Do you mean 1 giant pdf w/ many pages of duplicate plots, but w/ different `par` calls?

Comment: @gung No, I literally just meant the commands I outlined, in sequence. You'll see that after you set `mar`, `pin` has been _reset_ to something else. Setting one has an effect on the other (presumably it's recalculating based on the device size, to make sure everything fits...?) that I don't quite understand completely.